# How to separate btn's in a button group?

Tags: html, css

I made a group of 3 buttons based on the code found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_button_group_vertical). The issue is that currently, like in the source of the code, they are vertically touching each other. I would like to be able to space them out.

**How can I accomplish this, given the following code?**

The HTML

```
 <div class="navBarItems">
    <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
    <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
    <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>

    <!-- <ul>
      <li class="profileItem">My Profile</li>
      <li class="exploreItem">Explore</li>
      <li class="uploadItem">Upload</li>
    </ul> -->
  </div>
```

The CSS

```
.navBarItems button {
  background-color: #282828;
  border: none;
  /* 1px solid #282828;  */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 20px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 75%; /* Set a width if needed */
  font-size: 18px;
  font: Arial;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}

.navBarItems button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.navBarItems button:hover {
  background-color: #393939;
}
```

Here is what it looks like currently: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_button_group_vertical

Comment: Set top and margin on each button.  Eg: .btn-group button{  margin: 3px 0 0 3px; }

Comment: "Top and bottom margin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navBarItems button {
  background-color: #282828;
  border: none;
  /* 1px solid #282828;  */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 20px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 75%; /* Set a width if needed */
  font-size: 18px;
  font: Arial;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}

.navBarItems button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.navBarItems button:hover {
  background-color: #393939;
}

.navBarItems * {
 margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navBarItems">
    <button class="profileItem">My Profile</button>
    <button class="exploreItem">Explore</button>
    <button class="uploadItem">Upload</button>

    <!-- <ul>
      <li class="profileItem">My Profile</li>
      <li class="exploreItem">Explore</li>
      <li class="uploadItem">Upload</li>
    </ul> -->
  </div>
```

- `.navBarItems` will select the class
- `*` will select all child elements, which in this instance are of type `button`
- `margin: 5px 0 5px 0;` will apply `5px` margin to the top & the bottom of each button

Thus; **spaced out**!

If this solution helped you solve this issue, please mark it as accepted :)